# cannot go to detail view from table view on iphone

Tags: iphone

i have table view and when user click on any row then he should go to next view
but in my case its not working, what i am doing wrong here??

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller
        NSLog(@" push");// is working

        aDetail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];// not wokring




        [self.navigationController pushViewController:aDetail animated:YES];//not working




    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not working? Also you can use nil for the nibName and bundle and it will find the correct file for you.

Comment: When you say "not working", how exactly is it not working? Are you getting a compiler warning or error, a crash, a blank screen, or nothing happens other than the NSLog statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem, try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller

        // Don't forget to import DetailViewController.h at the top 
        // and then declare the type down here - see my revision to
        // the beginning of the next line. (I also remove the bundle
        // reference - it's not necessary as far as I know.

        DetailViewController * aDetail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil]; 
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:aDetail animated:YES];

       // Memory management - very important!
       // The view is retained by your parent
       // view, so you can and should release 
       // it here to avoid memory leaks.

       [aDetail release]; 
    }
```

Comment: got it . i was using View-controller instead of navigation controller in app delegate  now i changed and its working thanks